# CodeIgniter 4 - AJAX Request 404 on ONE route; All others work beautifully

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-4

I am again having issues with AJAX on the CodeIgniter 4 framework, and this time I am at a complete loss.

After weeks of researching on why the error was getting thrown, attempting different fixes, implementing different work-arounds, I am still stumped as to why this ONE class with defined routes refuses to accept the AJAX POST.

Before I begin, **I AM USING CODEIGNITER 4.1.9**, I have around 20 other classes, all with their own POST routes and validation and they ***ALL*** work. Every one of them allows for clean C.R.U.D. of data, but this particular class and the methods are returning a 404.

**Routes**

```
$routes->post('createNewCloudGoal', 'Platform\CloudNine::createNewCloudGoal');
$routes->post('getCloudGoal', 'Platform\CloudNine::getCloudGoal');
$routes->post('completeCloudGoal', 'Platform\CloudNine::completeCloudGoal');
$routes->post('deleteCloudGoal', 'Platform\CloudNine::deleteCloudGoal');
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#newC9GoalForm').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/createNewCloudGoal',
            data: form,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#createNewC9Goal').modal('hide');

                var r = JSON.parse(result);
                if(r.ret === '1' || r.ret === 1) {
                    new Noty({
                        type: 'success',
                        theme: 'relax',
                        text: r.msg,
                        timeout: 2420,
                        callbacks: {
                            afterClose: function() {
                                window.location.href = window.location.href;
                            }
                        }
                    }).show();
                } else {

                    new Noty({
                        type: 'error',
                        theme: 'relax',
                        text: r.msg,
                        timeout: 2420
                    }).show();
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(form.values);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

I would add the class code, but the request isn't even making it to the class itself, and is returning a 404.

The **Payload** in developers tools is showing the data that is put into the `FormData`, but the Preview is a BLANK PAGE, the status is 500, and when I double-click the file in the `Network` tab, it opens and shows the **404 Error**

YES, all of my code works wonderfully in every single other class, the routes work amazingly, and almost all the other AJAX request/POST I am sending is using and following the exact same structure as the one listed above, so I know its not some kind of syntax error. The URL field is working in **EVERY OTHER** call, so I don't want to hear the `base_url('site route')` code as it looks bad in JS and hasn't worked the number of different times I have tried to implement it. Routes exist for a reason.

I attempted to change the `contentType` to a whole slew of other options, and even saw someone mention that it should be `ConentType` with a capital C and that didn't do anything either.

All of my routes follow the same structure and work for the ***MYRIAD*** of other AJAX calls I am making, but this one particular request is being ridiculous and I cant test the data being received because it never reaches the defined route destination, and none of the return AJAX Error information assists with finding the base of the problem:

[image: Errors thrown when trying to CREATE]

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated as this one functionality is really all that is holding this step of the project back. Any clues or tips on how to trace the issue with devTools, maybe a way to get different error data (?), I dunno, but I am at a loss and am turning to the community :) Thanks for your help erverybody

**UPDATE**

@parttimeturtle thank you for the heads up! Although I did find the issue, I am stumped as to handle the resolution of this issue as this is a first time for me in this area:

```
 #8 {main}
ERROR - 2022-06-10 10:42:41 --> Unknown column 'complete' in 'where clause'
CRITICAL - 2022-06-10 10:42:47 --> syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'
#0 .../system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php(241): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->includeFile('...')
#1 .../system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php(219): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadInNamespace('App\\Controllers...')
#2 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadClass('App\\Controllers...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('App\\Controllers...')
#4 .../system/CodeIgniter.php(789): class_exists('\\App\\Controller...', true)
#5 .../system/CodeIgniter.php(397): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->startController()
#6 .../system/CodeIgniter.php(318): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(NULL, Object(Config\Cache), false)
#7 .../index.php(37): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
```

Scratching my head as I read this cause I dont have any issues with any of my other classes that are in the same directory as the one in question...

Still looking for the resolution...

**FINAL UPDATE**
Got it all figured out! The log files were indeed verbose, and after posting the last update I followed the trace and figured out the issues that were plaguing this system. Thank you to EVERYONE who assisted in figuring this thing out and I only wish I could get you all tacos for being so awesome. It indeed was a very ***SMALL*** syntax error buried deep in the code I hadn't been working in for a couple weeks and slipped my gaze.

Comment: Please add implementation of controller method and the logged error message.
500 means that your code has an error which is not handled by your app which might be a undefined index or an exception that is not catched. Also dont get blinded by "its the same" because its almost always not. Get something like insomnia or postman to test the requests by themselves (without browser).

Comment: @CodeSpirit The Logged error message is empty as displayed in the image above. If ther is another location where I can retrieve said error from, let me know becuase I have looked in just about every crevice. The controller method doesn't even receive the request when using ```var_dump($_POST)``` and the method name I copied viz ```CTRL+C``` and pasted it into the routes so it would be the same across the board. I will give Postman a try and post any status updates.

Comment: Kind of looks like the server is throwing a 500, not a 404. By default your project should be writing logs to `<projectroot>/writable/logs`.

Comment: @parttimeturtle -- see UPDATE in post and THANK YOU

Comment: @fangb0n3 The logs are pretty verbose. First you have an error in your SQL syntax and it seems theres also a syntax error.

Comment: @CodeSpirit
Thank you for your assistance! As soon as I posted the last update, It clicked in my head where the issue was generating and it got solved. I really appreciate you on this matter!

Comment: @parttimeturtle
Thank you for your assistance! As soon as I posted the last update, It clicked in my head where the issue was generating and it got solved. I really appreciate you on this matter!